# Gerenciar banco de dados Paradox com PHP 7

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, windows, paradox

Tenho um programa desenvolvido por *terceiros* e preciso gerenciar o banco de dados dele, que é feito em **paradox**.

Descobri a [**pxlib**](http://pxlib.sourceforge.net/) que, pelo que minhas pesquisas indicam, deve ser compilada para o **Windows**.

Tentei pegar a extensão (*pxlib.dll* e *ext/php_paradox.dll*) que vem no **XAMPP 1.7** e ativar no `php.ini`, mas não funcionou.

- Não posso converter o banco de dados *paradox*, pois o programa vai continuar em funcionamento. Preciso usar o programa e o *PHP* simultaneamente.
- Já consigo gerenciar o banco de dados *paradox* com um editor ([Paradox Data Editor](http://www.mitec.cz/pde.html)).

Se realmente precisa compilar (*e não copiar a extensão compilada*), como faço?

Utilizo **PHP 7** e **Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 bits)**.